# How to navigate to another html page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a main html file called default.html with two javascript files default.js and backend.js.

The two javascript files are added as follow in the main html

```
<script src="assets/js/backend.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/default.js"></script>
```

the default.js contains this setup

```
startUp()
  
eel.expose(startUp);
function startUp(){
 showNextPage()  
}

function showNextPage(){
 console.log("show next page")
 window.location = 'next.html'
 console.log("i guess the page did not change")
}
```

in backend.js if i call showNextPage() to execute on page load, the page change works

```
showNextPage()

class auth {
}

class storageManager {
}
```

but if I call showNextPage() to execute within a class like this

```
class auth {
     //...
 showNextPage()
}
```

only the console.log messages in showNextPage() are performed and not the page change.

I don't know what is going on, for some reason it appears the window.location change only works early on page load.

what could be causing this and how can i fix it?

I tried

```
window.location.href
window.location.replace
```

and other similar methods. The main thing is that the function is proven to work but not within a class which has confused me for days now. I have triple checked my code multiple times but no result

Comment: The first thing that `backend.js` does is call a function from `default.js`, which may not have loaded yet. You should add `defer` to the `script` references so that they wait until everything is loaded before they run.

Comment: @ScottMarcus how do I add a defer

Comment: Its best to use window.location.href. Add defer to the script tag as an attribute. You should probably listen for the page ready event as well.

Comment: @John I tried that and many other methods

Comment: `<script src="..." defer></script>`

Comment: @ScottMarcus i tried  adding defer still no change. the thing is backend.js works fine even without defer, the page transition works when called immediately after page load but wierdly not when called within a class

Comment: It's not syntactically correct to put code within a class definition except to define properties and methods. Why are you trying to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Try making your `default.js` file into this

```
 startUp()
  
eel.expose(startUp);
function startUp(){
    
 showNextPage()  
    
}

function showNextPage(){

 console.log("show next page")
  window.pathname = '/next.html' //IMPORTANT PART.. origin is the page, like https://stackoverflow.com.. pathname is everything past that

 console.log("i guess the page did not change")
}
```

I hope it worked